# How Linux resists single event upsets?

Tags: linux, operating-system, open-source, low-level, fault-tolerance

I am collecting information about single event upsets for my report at the university.
I found plenty of helpful articles for my theme, but I got stuck with operating systems' resistance against SEU. I chose Linux as one that's being used in real-time systems.
I think this OS have some fault-tolerance module that covers most problems. But I can't find any fresh articles/documents on how it works in Linux. 
Let me share what I found:

- [This one](https://www.linux.co.cr/distributions/review/1995/0416.html) is some AD for FT-Linux from 1995;
- [This](http://www.popcornlinux.org/images/publications/CloudDP_2016.pdf) and [this](http://www.popcornlinux.org/images/publications/ftos_icdcs17.pdf) are too complex, and they were made based on Popcorn Linux.

I am sure that the principles are the same, but I'd like to find some code examples with commentaries from the Linux source (if it is implemented in the core) or utility names for FT in Linux. And how to run it.
Or maybe all FT systems are commercial and non-opensource? Or they don't have enough attention?

Comment: What makes you think Linux resists them?

Comment: I think it may resist them with some built-in instruments. Or there is something we can install to resist them.

Comment: I expect that most Linux distributions depend on the hardware to be resistant.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to focus on those that don't. Hardware resistance deserves its own topic.

Comment: Anyway, this would be more appropriate on [unix.se].

Comment: Didn't know about that part of StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Solved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678954/502657), on unix.stackexchange